# Ajax CORS iframe, cookie not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

i have an iframe with `src` set to (let say) `domainA.com` and parent url is `domainB.com`, from this iframe i make an ajax call to `domainA.com/ajax.asp`, this works in chrome and firefox, but not with safari and IE. bellow are complete header request for chrome and safari.

**REQUEST HEADER (Chrome)**

```
POST /Ajax.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: domainA.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Accept: */*
Origin: http://test.takeoutmenuz.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://domainA.com/menu.asp?userid=1025
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6
Cookie: userid=1025; ASPSESSIONIDAQCQASBD=IDGHMLJDBHOKJFBIKMCNDHDA; ZZZZZ=here
```

**REQUEST HEADER (Safari)**

```
POST /Ajax.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: domainA.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Accept: */*
Origin: http://test.takeoutmenuz.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://domainA.com/menu.asp?userid=1025
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6
```

as you see, there is no `Cookie` header in safari, based on explanation from [this page](http://blog.prowebsoftware.net/2013/08/safari-cors-requests-withcredentials/) the problem is that `Cookie` stuff (if i not mistaken). how to make it work without `Cookie`, should i do something on response header in Ajax.asp or do something in ajax script (i already add `withCredential` field to it)?

Comment: Is domainA.com properly specifying that credentials can be passed by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`? If you're using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` instead of actually specifying `test.takeoutmenuz.com` then safari would be performing correctly by not sending the cookie. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests

Comment: In other words, if you want to allow cookies to be transmitted, you must use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: test.takeoutmenuz.com`. I don't think the fact that you're using iframes has anything to do with this.

Comment: so this header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` should be send from domainA.com? i will let you know if it's working or not, i have no access to the Ajax.asp file

Comment: Correct, domainA.com needs these headers to be in the response.

Comment: by the way `withCredentials` is not there untill i made it there, it was not working as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this particular safari security feature to say whether or not anything i have said will actually solve your problem.

Comment: Not sending the cookie really isn't an option, as without it the client wouldn't be authorized.

Comment: Does this work if you load the same page (domainA.com) not in an iframe and make the same AJAX request?

Comment: yes, it work good when loaded not in an iframe.

Comment: Ever figure this out?